# Constraints Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, constraints

I have fiddled with the constraints for a while and for some reason on a view bigger than the view in the main storyboard looks awful. Right now it's on reset to suggested constraints. Those are my constraints below, I'm not sure what's going on. Is there something wrong with my Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is the yellow box supposed to look like? Square (like on the right side) or rectangular (like on the left)?

Comment: Like on the left. But for some reason it makes it a huge rectangle. I'm not sure why. I'm using XCode 7.1 on El Capitan.

Comment: Do you want it vertically centered? Or a constant distance from the top?

Comment: @joern It's already vertically centered, I want it to not turn into a rectangle like it is in the preview to the right.

Comment: "Is there something wrong with my Xcode or am I doing something wrong?" Always assume it's you.

Comment: @matt Yeah I agree. I'm just not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You haven't explained what you _want_ to do.

Comment: @matt I want the rectangle to not be a rectangle. And conform to the size of iPhone.

Comment: "I want the rectangle to not be a rectangle." I don't know what that means. How can a rectangle not be a rectangle? "And conform to the size of iPhone" What does _that_ mean? - Do you even know what you want?

Comment: @matt Ok, let me try and explain more clearly. The left is my storyboard. It's a 4 inch iphone screen. With a button. I have constraints on it. But for some reason on all other sizes of iphones it turns into a large button.

Comment: "But for some reason on all other sizes of iphones it turns into a large button" No, not "for some reason". It is doing _exactly what you told it to do_. If that isn't what you want, then don't do that. For example, don't give it any trailing constraint or bottom constraint. Instead, give it a width constraint and a height constraint.

Comment: @matt I do. I try everything and I a lot of times get red constraints. It used to be really easy where I can just reset to suggested constraints but now it doesn't work most of the time. And I always get red constraints.

Comment: Red constraints mean conflict. You can't have both trailing and width, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button stretches because you pinned it to the top and to the bottom. So on a larger screen the distance from the top and the bottom stays the same which means that the button is stretched.

**Keeping the size of the button**

The keep the size of the bottom an center is vertically und horizontally you have to give a **width** and a **height** constraint and a **centerY** and **centerX** constraint:

[image]

**Keeping the aspect ratio of the button**

**EDIT**: This is a cleaner solution suggested by [Sega-Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254172/sega-zero):

To scale the button according to the screen size but keep its aspect ratio you have to set an **equal width** constraint (with a multiplier) between button an its superview, an **aspect ratio** constraint and **centerY** and **centerX** constraints:

[image]

Comment: This makes it the same on all view, I want it to fit all views but not like a giant rectangle that's happening on my screen.

Comment: So you want to keep the aspect ratio but make it bigger on larger screens?

Comment: Exactly but for some reason my constraints are messed up. I've tried redownloading Xcode and deleting derived data and creating a new project but none of that works.

Comment: Your constraints are not messed up, they are just not the right constraints for what you are trying to achieve. Please see my updated answer on how to keep the aspect ration of your button

Comment: Then, why don't just make centering constraints, aspect constraint and equal width (or height) constraint to it's superview, with some appropriate multiplier? Something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/93mo4.jpg

Comment: You are right! I edited my answer, thanks for pointing that out!